# Enable remote printing options with cups-lpd

Tags: printing, cups, lpd

I am trying to print from SCO OpenServer remotely to a CUPS-LPD daemon running on a Red Hat Linux machine but it is dropping any print options from the print request.

For example:

```
lp -d remote-print-queue -o landscape print-file
```

The options presented to the filter / backend only contains a job-uuid:

```
argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:96ba0666-ca3d-337b-69bf-81f70e9fa2a7"
```

Is it possible to enable the pass-through of options using lpd remote printing?